# Drag & Drop SVG Shapes Using D3 and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js

experimenting with AngularJS and D3 I'm trying to figure out on how to drag & drop svg elements from one svg to another one. Do you have any hints or experiences on how to do that?

Regards,
Andi

An [Example](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/abuechler/dragdrop/master/demo/draganddrop.html) would be to drag a circle from the right square and drop it onto the left square. The examples source is on [github](https://github.com/abuechler/dragdrop/tree/master/demo).

Comment: [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/thudfactor/6611441) is an example that demonstrates it with HTML and SVG. In general, it's going to be much easier to drag and drop within a single SVG if that's an option for you.

Answer (score -1):

I hve done this with javaxcript. Maybe you can use some of its features. It works in IE and Chrome. FF is in the process of implimenting the needed intersection list method.

This example below shows dragging elements and dropping them into the various viewPorts(SVG roots).
Uses matrix transforms. It can seamlessly drag/drop elements that have previously been transformed and reside it different viewPorts. It employs getScreenCTM,  createSVGTransform and binds the element to a transform List
Each viewport target is determined by using an SVGRect object and employes checkIntersection.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Drag and Drop Into Viewports</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
<h4> Drag and Drop Into Viewports</h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
This example shows dragging elements and dropping them into the various viewPorts(SVG roots).
Uses matrix transforms. It can seamlessly drag/drop elements that have previously been transformed and reside it different viewPorts. It employs <b>getScreenCTM</b>,  <b>createSVGTransform</b> and binds the element to a <b>transform List</b>
Each viewport target is determined by using an <b>SVGRect</b> object and employes <b>checkIntersection</b>.
</div>
<table>
<tr><td align=left>
 <b>Scenerio:</b><br />
A The parent SVG root(mySVG) with viewBox=0 0 400 400.<br />
It contains the the draggable red circles. The white circles are inside the rect viewPorts<br />
1.) The blue rect element is contained in, and fills, its own svg root<br />
3.) The maroon rect element is contained  in, and fills,  its own  svg root.<br />
4.) The orange rect element is contained  in, and fills,  its own  svg root<br /> with viewPort=10 10 50 50.<br />
<br />
(View the SVG Source to verify where the circles are being dropped.)
</td>
<td align=left>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<svg overflow="visible" width="100" height="100"  x="20" y="60" pointer-events="all"  id="blueSVG" >
<rect id="blueRect"  x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="white" cx="20" cy="20" r="15" />
</svg>
<svg overflow="visible"  width="100" height="100"  x="280" y="60"  pointer-events="all"  id="maroonSVG"  >
<rect  id="maroonRect"  x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="maroon" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="white" cx="20" cy="20" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="white" cx="60" cy="20" r="15" />
</svg>
<svg overflow="visible"  width="100" height="100"  x="120" y="200" viewBox="10 10 50 50" pointer-events="all"  id="orangeSVG" >
<rect id="orangeRect"   x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="white" cx="20" cy="20" r="15" />
</svg>
<svg id="WrapperSVG" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="40" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="80" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="120" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="160" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="200" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="240" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="280" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="320" cy="30" r="15" />
<circle onmousedown=startDrag(evt) onmousemove=drag(evt) onmouseup=endDrag(evt)  fill="red" cx="360" cy="30" r="15" />
</svg>
</div>
</td>
</tr></table>
<br />SVG Source:<br />
<textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
<br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>
<script id=myScript>
var TransformRequestObj
var TransList
var DragTarget=null;
var Dragging = false;
var OffsetX = 0;
var OffsetY = 0;
//---mouse down over element---
function startDrag(evt)
{
    if(!Dragging) //---prevents dragging conflicts on other draggable elements---
    {
        DragTarget = evt.target;
        //---bring this viewPort to top---
        if(DragTarget.ownerSVGElement!=mySVG)
            mySVG.appendChild(DragTarget.ownerSVGElement)
        //---bring this element to top---
        DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.appendChild(DragTarget)

        //---reference point to its respective viewport--
        var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
        pnt.x = evt.clientX;
        pnt.y = evt.clientY;
        //---elements transformed and/or in different(svg) viewports---
        var sCTM = DragTarget.getScreenCTM();
        var Pnt = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());

        TransformRequestObj = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform()
        //---attach new or existing transform to element, init its transform list---
        var myTransListAnim=DragTarget.transform
        TransList=myTransListAnim.baseVal

        OffsetX = Pnt.x
        OffsetY = Pnt.y

        Dragging=true;
    }
}
//---mouse move---
function drag(evt)
{
    if(Dragging)
    {
        var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
        pnt.x = evt.clientX;
        pnt.y = evt.clientY;
        //---elements in different(svg) viewports, and/or transformed ---
        var sCTM = DragTarget.getScreenCTM();
        var Pnt = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());
        Pnt.x -= OffsetX;
        Pnt.y -= OffsetY;

        TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Pnt.x,Pnt.y)
        TransList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
        TransList.consolidate()
    }
}
var ViewPortTarget
//--mouse up---
function endDrag(evt)
{
    Dragging = false;
    //--which viewPort is the element over ?---
    var isBlueSVG = mySVG.checkIntersection(DragTarget, BlueObjRect)
    var isOrangeSVG = mySVG.checkIntersection(DragTarget, OrangeObjRect)
    var isMaroonSVG = mySVG.checkIntersection(DragTarget, MaroonObjRect)

    if(isBlueSVG)
        ViewPortTarget=blueSVG
    else if(isOrangeSVG)
        ViewPortTarget=orangeSVG
    else if(isMaroonSVG)
        ViewPortTarget=maroonSVG
    else
        ViewPortTarget=mySVG

    ViewPortTarget.appendChild(DragTarget)
    var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
    pnt.x = evt.clientX;
    pnt.y = evt.clientY;
    //---elements in different(svg) viewports, and/or transformed ---
    var sCTM = DragTarget.getScreenCTM();
    var Pnt = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());
    Pnt.x -= OffsetX;
    Pnt.y -= OffsetY;

    TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Pnt.x,Pnt.y)
    TransList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
    TransList.consolidate()

    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
//---build the viewPort intersect rect obj---
var BlueObjRect
var OrangeObjRect
var MaroonObjRect
function setViewportRect()
{
    WrapperSVG.appendChild(blueSVG)
    var bb=WrapperSVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    BlueObjRect=mySVG.createSVGRect()

    BlueObjRect.x=bbx
    BlueObjRect.y=bby
    BlueObjRect.width=bbw
    BlueObjRect.height=bbh
    mySVG.insertBefore(blueSVG,WrapperSVG)

    WrapperSVG.appendChild(orangeSVG)
    var bb=WrapperSVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    OrangeObjRect=mySVG.createSVGRect()

    OrangeObjRect.x=bbx
    OrangeObjRect.y=bby
    OrangeObjRect.width=bbw
    OrangeObjRect.height=bbh
    mySVG.insertBefore(orangeSVG,WrapperSVG)

    WrapperSVG.appendChild(maroonSVG)
    var bb=WrapperSVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height

    MaroonObjRect=mySVG.createSVGRect()
    MaroonObjRect.x=bbx
    MaroonObjRect.y=bby
    MaroonObjRect.width=bbw
    MaroonObjRect.height=bbh
    mySVG.appendChild(maroonSVG)
    mySVG.insertBefore(maroonSVG,WrapperSVG)
}
</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    setViewportRect()
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
    jsValue.value=myScript.text
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```